# WebServer V4 Template issue

Tags: pki

Recently I created Webserver V4 template for Computer authentication in environment.
On the Subject tab, selected Build from this Active Directory Information and the Name format as DNS Name.
While requesting for certificate, I'm getting the below error message:

"Certificate not issued (Denied) Denied by Policy Module The DNS name is unavailable and cannot be added to the Subject Alternate name. 0x8009480f (-2146875377 CERTSRV_E_SUBJECT_DNS_REQUIRED)
Certificate Request Processor: The DNS name is unavailable and cannot be added to the Subject Alternate name. 0x8009480f (-2146875377 CERTSRV_E_SUBJECT_DNS_REQUIRED)
Denied by Policy Module"
In the inf file, I provided Subject name and SAN name as the Computer dns name.

Comment: This isn't a programming question - it should be on Server Fault or Super User instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the template expects the Subject and SAN from AD and not from the submitted request file.

ADCS tries to get the DNS name from AD for the entity submitting the request - you. As you don't have a DNS entry, it fails.

If you run the command as Administrator and add the `-AdminForceMachine` flag, it will use the identity of the computer where you are running the command instead, which should have a DNS entry.

Make sure you run it from the computer you want certified by the CA, otherwise you will end up with the wrong name.